# How to decrease 1cm arrow length in commutative diagram on the base?

Tags: xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix{
& Y\ar[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^{h} & \\
& S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could ask your question in the body of the question template. For example, it's not clear to me how long your arrows should be, if there are constraints on the arrow heads, .... Also it would show you have put in some effort, which will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Decrease base length of the symmetric diagram.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar I added the picture. I hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: You can try with `\xymatrix@C-10pt{...}` to reduce the intercolumn space, but the `h` label will clash with the diagonal arrow labeled `\psi_{j}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The command `\xymatrix` has extensions for alterating the standard dimensions used.  These take the form `\xymatrix` followed by `@` followed by a letter, then `=`, `+=` or `-=` followed by a dimension.  The syntax sets, increases or reduces the dimension corresponding to the letter. In particular,

```
\xymatrix@C-=0.5cm
```

will decrease all intercolumn spacing by `0.5cm`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  $\xymatrix{
  & Y\ar[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^{h} & \\
  & S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
  R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$

  $\xymatrix@C-=0.5cm{
  & Y\ar[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^{h} & \\
  & S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
  R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In this case the label `h` now comes a bit too close to one of the arrows.  You can move the `h` downwards by writing `\ar[d]^(.65){h}`, so it is place `65%` of the way from `Y` to `S` instead:

[image: Adjusted output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix@C-=0.5cm{
& Y\ar[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^(.65){h} & \\
& S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (same approach as Mr. Swann's) with use of `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep= .5cm]
       & Y \ar{ddl}[swap]{\psi_i} \ar{d}[near end]{h} \ar{ddr}{\psi_j} & \\
       & S \ar{dl}{\pi_i} \ar{dr}[swap]{\pi_j} & \\
       R_i \ar{rr}[swap]{\mu_{ji}} & & R_j
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Explanation why I downvoted the contribution: Actually the question is on how to do this with xymatrix. Laudible, if you use the answer for providing an advertisement for a completely different package but not really what the xymatrix user needs here.